# Differences between if else in Django and Flask

Tags: python, django

I have just starting learning to code in Python. Why do they have different style in terms of coding? Can someone explain in detailed on the whole process flow?

Comment: Django = "Web Server", tkinter = "standard Python interface to the Tk GUI toolkit". They are two _vastly_ different things...

Comment: Can I also create a web server using tkinter?

Comment: Tkinter is a GUI toolkit, it doesn't serve things. You could write a web server that has a Tkinter control interface, but there's not much point in that.

Comment: No you cannot. Perhaps instead of asking this question you should first find out what _exactly_ tkinter and Django are, I would say the premise of this question lies in the _lack of research_ you did before asking it...

Comment: What do you mean ? AKX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django is a web framework. It allows you to create Web apps accessible via the Internet.

Tkinter is a GUI framework. It allows you to create local applications on your device/ wherever the app is installed.